# python3 dynamic variable access in for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a few Pandas dataframes that I want to loop through at once to do some initial verification and debugging, but I can't figure out how to automate it.  I've read a bunch of posts on here and various blogs of people trying to do something similar and the responses all tend towards "That's the wrong way to do that", but I haven't found anything that actually does what I'm looking for.  In slightly-more-than-pseudocode, what I'm trying to do is:

```py
for i in ('train', 'test', 'address', 'latlon'):
        print('{}:'.format(i))
        print(<i>.head())  ## what should <i> be?
```

In shell and Perl scripts it's as simple as encapsulating the variable name in {} (`${i}`), but I can't find a Python equivalent.  I've tried various permutations of `format()`, but I keep getting `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'head'` (I get the same error if I try just `print(i.head())`).  I've also tried using `globals()`, but I get a key error on the first loop.

This is just for early-stage development and will get removed, so it doesn't have to be super clean, but it's an issue that I've ran into a few times now and it's really aggravating me.

EDIT:  After some trial and error I got the below to work. Hopefully this will help someone in the future.

```py
frames = dict({'train': train.head(), 'test': test.head(), 'address':address.head(), 'latlon': latlon.head()})

for i in frames.keys():
    print('{}'.format(i))
    print(frames[i])
```

I still don't understand how this is supposed to be an improvement over something like ${i} available in other languages, but it works.

Comment: Don't do this. Just use a dictionary or list instead.

Comment: Just put the real variable in your tuple, instead of a string containing its name: `for i in (train, test ...): print(i.head())`

Comment: @Carcigenicate, that answer isn't helpful.  There's a hundred examples of people saying literally that exact thing, but if I could see how a dictionary or list would solve my problem I wouldn't be here.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille, that got me closer, but it causes the `print('{}:'.format(i))` to print the entire df instead of the name.  If I can only have the name or the contents I'll take the latter, but it helps to have the name when it loops through to the next df.

Comment: @jml Have a dictionary mapping, for example, `"train"` to the object that you want `<i>.head` to be. Or just stick the train, test, address... objects in a list and iterate over them. `for obj in [train_obj, test_obj]: print(obj.head())` like Thierry showed.

Comment: That helped me get it sorted out.  I added specifics as a separate answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables